# Commutative square of module of differential is cartesian?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, kahler-differentials

Is it true that the following square is Cartesian? $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
R @>{d}>> \Omega^{1}_{R} \\
@VVV @VVV\\
\widehat{R} @>{ \widehat{d}}>> \Omega^{1}_{\widehat{R}}
\end{CD}
where R is any  regular local algebra over rational number. Any help would be great.

Comment: The answer is no, already for the second square. Take for $R$ the ring $\mathbb{Q}[T]$ localized at $(T)$.  The differential form $(1+T)^{-1}dT$ becomes exact in  $\Omega ^1_{\widehat{R}}$, but is not exact in  $\Omega ^1_{R}$.

Comment: Doesn't the above comment answer your question???

Comment: Yes. I just edited and removed the unnecessary part of question.

Comment: My comment answers your question (negatively) as it stands now.

Comment: I think your answer still stands correct. Because anyway you gave counter example to second square and it had nothing to do with first square.